# 3 dollar bet has 60% chance of paying $5.5, how much money must I start with for a 90% chance of earning 5x my starting funds?

Tags: probability, statistics, gambling

Title has a specific example, but I'm interested in an equation I can put in my spreadsheet, so let's define some variables.

I've been offered a bet and I can take it as many times as I want.
C = how much I have to pay to play
P = probability of winning
R = the amount of money returned if I win
T = the total amount of money I start with
K = probability of having M * T dollars before losing it all

I'm looking to solve for T given all the other variables.

I'm fine with calculating expected values and odds of winning / losing some specific number of permutations, but this problem seems to involve the residual amount of money left from past wins, makes me think I need to break out calculus and integrate something. Not really sure how I should approach this (other than coding a simulation, but I'd prefer an equation).

Comment: Go to Huygens result (unfair coin flipping). You should imagine an opponent playing with the same bankroll as you. P(you doubling your money)=P( your opponent going broke) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin

Comment: I think that ignores many of the variables in my question, I edited the values in the title to try and make seem like less of a zero sum value doubling coin flip.

Comment: Okay. If you want to return 5x initial value, you should set your opponent’s bankroll at 4x your bankroll. Note that, P(winning up to your target) + P(going broke) = 1. I know that the wiki article doesn’t involve “paying to play the game”, but that should be relatively easy to implement. Can you define your variables more clearly? Is “T” after you pay the “C”, or before?

Comment: Most of these questions could be answered by viewing this as a classical 'gambler's ruin' problem---from well-known formulas.